# an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/6/00/0000000006 while reading upstream

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

> Процессор 7 X Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2288G CPU @ 3.70GHz
>
> Оперативная память     14023 MB
>
> Размер дискового пространства 58.80 GB
>
> Файл подкачки (swap)  2047 MB
>
> FastCGI (Apache)

При каждом обращении к сайту вылезало предупреждение  `upstream response is buffered to a temporary`

В `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` в http добавил след параметры

```
proxy_buffering on; 
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers 32 4k; 
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
```

Предупреждение стало реже появляться , но все равно появляется. Прошу помощи, какие параметры еще надо увеличить  ?

Comment: только proxy_max_temp_file_size оставьте, значение 0 это фактически отключение записи в temp файл. если не поможет - верните остальное

Comment: А почему вы считаете это проблемой?